# RandomizedSearchCV sampling distribution

Tags: scikit-learn, python-3.8

According to RandomizedSearchCV [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) (emphasis mine):

> **param_distributions: dict or list of dicts**
>
> Dictionary with parameters names (str) as keys and distributions or
> lists of parameters to try. Distributions must provide a rvs method
> for sampling (such as those from scipy.stats.distributions). If a list
> is given, it is sampled uniformly. **If a list of dicts is given, first
> a dict is sampled uniformly, and then a parameter is sampled using
> that dict as above.**

If my understanding of the above is correct, both algorithms (XGBClassifier and LogisticRegression) in the following example should be sampled with high probability (>99%), given n_iter = 10.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


param_grid = [
              {'scaler': [StandardScaler()],
               'feature_selection': [RFE(estimator=XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False, eval_metric='logloss'))],
               'feature_selection__n_features_to_select': [3],
               'classification': [XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False, eval_metric='logloss')],
               'classification__n_estimators': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000],
               'classification__max_depth': [2, 5, 10],
               },
              {'scaler': [StandardScaler()],
               'feature_selection': [RFE(estimator=LogisticRegression())],
               'feature_selection__n_features_to_select': [3],
               'classification': [LogisticRegression()],
               'classification__C': [0.1],
               },
              ]


pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('feature_selection', RFE(estimator=LogisticRegression())),
                       ('classification', LogisticRegression())])

classifier = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_distributions=param_grid,
                                scoring='neg_brier_score', n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)

data = load_breast_cancer()
X = data.data
y = data.target.ravel()
classifier.fit(X, y)
```

What happens though is that every time I run it XGBClassifier gets chosen 10/10 times. I would expect one candidate to come from Logistic Regresion since the probability for each dict to be sampled is 50-50.
If the search space between the two algoritms is more balanced ('classification__n_estimators': [100]) then the sampling works as expected.
Can someone clarify what's going on here?

Comment: When quoting from an online source (such as documentation), please include also the link (edited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is incorrect behavior.  There's an [Issue filed](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18057): when all the entries are lists (none are scipy distributions), [the current code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18057) selects points from the `ParameterGrid`, which means it will disproportionately choose points from the larger dictionary-grid from your list.

Until a fix gets merged, you might be able to work around this by using a scipy distribution for something you don't care about, say for `verbose`?